# Не устанавливаются пакеты

Tags: python

При установке любого пакета pip install * вылетает такая ошибка (переустанавливал и Python v3.10.8 и PyCharm v2022.2.1 - ничего не меняется)

> ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py",
> line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
> status = run_func(*args)   File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py",
> line 247, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)   File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
> line 369, in run
> requirement_set = resolver.resolve(   File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py",
> line 92, in resolve
> result = self._result = resolver.resolve(   File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py",
> line 481, in resolve
> state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)  ...   File "C:\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 955, in parse
> p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)   File "C:\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 444, in _parse_sub
> itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,   File "C:\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 526, in _parse
> code = _escape(source, this, state)   File "C:\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 427, in _escape
> raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape)) re.error: bad escape \c at position 17

Comment: А более старый питон не пробовали? Зачем вам новейший, с новыми версиями всегда проблемы совместимости сначала вылазят.

Comment: Нет. )) Видимо с этого и начну. Если что отпишусь.  Спасибо.